# Is this standard behavior? Div flows out of container

Tags: css

Is this standard CSS behavior?

[image]

How does one get the container to wrap around the button?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/yepw7oLw/

CSS:

```
.button {
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <a class="button">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted an answer and then re-read your question. do you want the width of the container to only go as far as the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your `a.button` element is currently being displayed as `inline`. `Margin` and `Padding` values applied to the top and bottom of `inline` elements don't impact elements around it, because the browser doesn't want to affect the flow.

To fix this, add `display: inline-block` to the `a.button` element.

This will force the browser to treat it as `block` for all rules regarding styling, and treat it as `inline` for placement on the page.

Comment: Kudos for AndyM for editing my answer with deep explanation why inline-block works.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display: block;
```

to .button

Answer (score 1):

Generally I wouldn't recommend adding padding to an anchor `<a>` tag.

Add the padding and other styles to a `<div>` instead, with the anchor encompassing that div: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c737767/3/)**

New HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <a href='#'>
        <div class='button'>Test</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

EDIT: in my JSFiddle example above, the width of the grey button defaults to 100% of the container, but you can change this if required by adding a width value to the `.test` div.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
 display: block;
```

as suggested and add a width to the button so it is not the full length of your div, e.g:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.button {
    display: block;
    width: 4%;
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```